# Value type being prepended to value of option element in a select dropdown using ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The HTML looks like it does below:

```
<select id="frontend-select" ng-model="tech.backEndValue" 
    ng-options="item.value as (item.name | translate) for item in techBackend">
</select>
```

The output of this is:

```
<select ng-model="tech.backEndValue" ng-options="item.value as (item.name | translate) for item in techBackend">
    <option value="string:JAVA" label="Java" selected="selected">Java</option
    <option value="string:PHP" label="PHP">PHP</option>
</select>
```

Why are the values always prepended with the value type?

Comment: You solve this? I have same problem

Comment: @brunocascio Did you solve this?